# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'never' when map through array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mapping

getting array from API and storing it into Movie state but when I try to map that movie I got the error:

> "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'never'."

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MoviePoster from "../../Components/MoviePoster";

function Home() {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState();
  const API_Url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_TMBD_KEY}`;

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies();
  }, []);

  async function getMovies() {
    const api = await fetch(API_Url);
    const result = await api.json();
    setMovie(result.results);
    console.log(result.results);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {movie?.map((data:any) => {
        <MoviePoster key={data} {...data} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

> the changes that I have applied... I just removed the common API part

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MoviePoster from "../../Components/MoviePoster";

interface MovieList {
  title: string,
  id: string
}

function Home() {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState<MovieList[]>([]);
  

  return (
    <div>
      {movie?.map((data:any) => {
        <MoviePoster key={data.id} {...data.title} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

> "consoled data image...."

[image: consoled data]

Comment: even though i am getting array of movies on the console.

Comment: Can you show example of how the console log looks like

Comment: i have added the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to return from the map

```
  return (
    <div>
      {movie?.map((data:any) => {
        return <MoviePoster key={data} {...data} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

instead of

```
return (
    <div>
      {movie?.map((data:any) => {
        <MoviePoster key={data} {...data} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

**Created a codesandbox demo with this components. Have a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-dubinsky-lmfwjr?file=/src/App.js)**

Comment: wow man it worked thanks alot i have been on this problem for past 1 day. man thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to what has been said by Hatana in the comments, you could also add a loading screen. That way you can be sure that you have your data in your array before the component is rendered.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MoviePoster from "../../Components/MoviePoster";

interface MovieList {
  movieList: [];
}

function Home() {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState<MovieList>();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const API_Url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie? 
api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_TMBD_KEY}`;

useEffect(() => {
  getMovies();
  setLoading(false);
}, []);

async function getMovies() {
  const api = await fetch(API_Url);
  const result = await api.json();
  setMovie(result.results);
  console.log(result.results);
}

if (loading) {
  return <div>Loading</div>;
}

return (
  <div>
    {movie?.map((data: any) => {
      <MoviePoster key={data} {...data} />;
    })}
  </div>
);

export default Home;
```

Comment: if `movie` is an array, we don't need to do that. `.map` will not fail on an empty array

Comment: That is right, adding the loading was just to prevent à render without the data.